# Prevent Vim from selecting less than 2 characters?

Tags: vim, vi, intellij-idea, phpstorm, pycharm

I use Vim more and more, and I installed the plugin `ideaVim` in my IDE from JetBrains (`pyCharm`, `phpStorm`).

I still use the mouse a lot to navigate and select text, and sometimes when I click in the file to position the cursor, it selects the character I clicked on and switches to visual mode.

Can I configure Vim to prevent that kind oh behaviour? I would like to prevent any switch to visual mode unless the mouse selection has more than two characters.

Any hints, or other ways to prevent this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You actually want to stop `visual mode` when moved cursor using mouse.

I think your plugins might have changed the mouse mode to `a`.

```
 :set mouse=a                     //This causes visual mode.
```

Change it to

```
 :set mouse=r
```

in command line. Or, put this line in your ~/.vimrc.
If that doesn't work, then you can put

```
 :au BufEnter *.* :set mouse=r
```

in ~/.vimrc.

Now, when you move the mouse, it will not select through visual mode.